# Copy cell value if next cell matchs

Tags: excel

I'd like to copy the longitude/latitude value to between 2 list of countries, but not all countries name matches. I was able to use conditional format to fix some of the names. What formula can I use to copy the lon/lat value from column E/F to B/C if value in A matches D. 
[image]

Link: [My sheet on gDoc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gM138gBM4gGXeJSe_Oruq2FIBiy9Q_0Ddlp6ItNPDmI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D:$D, A2)=0,"",VLOOKUP(A2,$D:$F,2,FALSE))
```

is able to solve this problem after some try and error.